# Symfony2 redis intempestive logging out

Tags: symfony, session, redis

In our Symfony project we configured sessions to be stored in Redis

```
session:
    handler_id: snc_redis.session.handler
    cookie_lifetime: 3600
```

Everything works properly but sometimes we are logged out. I checked in redis and I still see my session with correct TTL but I'm logged out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer. 
The session was not refresh. So this session expire after 1 hour (in my case), even if the user is active.

To avoid this behavior you should refresh the session on each request.

**services.xml file :**

```
<service id="app.session_listener"
                 class="My\TestBundle\EventListener\SessionListener">
            <tag name="kernel.event_subscriber" />
</service>
```

**SessionListener file :**

```
<?php

namespace My\TestBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

class SessionListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{

    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $event->getRequest()->getSession()->migrate();
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            KernelEvents::REQUEST => 'onKernelRequest',
        );
    }
}
```